# Data Template Binding not working even after setting the DataType

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have some data templates that are defined as follows. I am using a DataTemplateSelector to assign each data template to a ControlTemplate when something is selected on the UI based on the Enum (Please see the DataTemplateSelector below).

Problem is when I try to bind controls inside the DataTemplate, even though the DataContext is set to the ViewModel, I get a binding exception like

"BindingExpression path error: 'STMLocationItems' property not found on 'Driver.BarcodeParser.ParserLocation'. BindingExpression: Path='STMLocationItems' DataItem='Driver.BarcodeParser.ParserLocation'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'Object')". Please help.

Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="STMTemplate" x:DataType="viewModel:BarCodeServiceViewModel">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="/Application.GlobalizationLibrary/Resources/BarCodeServiceGoToScanLabel"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding STMLocationItems,Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate  x:Key="OutputTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="/Application.GlobalizationLibrary/Resources/BarCodeServiceGoToScanLabel"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.OutputLocationItems,Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

<common:LocationDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelectorBasedOnLocation" 
                                           STMTemplate="{StaticResource STMTemplate}"
                                           OutputTemplate="{StaticResource OutputTemplate}"
                                           PRMTemplate="{StaticResource PRMTemplate}"
                                           LabTemplate="{StaticResource LabTemplate}"></common:LocationDataTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
<ContentControl x:Name="CustomContentControl" DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedLocation.Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelectorBasedOnLocation}"/>
                    </Grid>
```

This is my DataTemplateSelector.

```
public class LocationDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate STMTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate OutputTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PRMTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate LabTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(ParserLocation))
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case ParserLocation.SampleTransport:
                        {
                            return STMTemplate;
                        }
                    case ParserLocation.OutputCarousel:
                        {
                            return OutputTemplate;
                        }
                    case ParserLocation.LyseCarousel:
                        {
                            return PRMTemplate;
                        }
                    case ParserLocation.AntibodyCarousel:
                        {
                            return LabTemplate;
                        }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the enum in a different namespace.

```
public enum ParserLocation { Unknown = -1, AntibodyCarousel = 0, LyseCarousel, ReactionPlate, OutputCarousel, SampleTransport, External, BeadMixer, DryCarouselLeft, DryCarouselRight }
```

Xaml.cs: Within the constructor setting the DataContext

```
public BarCodeServiceView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = LifetimeScope.Resolve<IBarCodeServiceViewModel>();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
```

This is my BarCodeServiceViewModel

```
public class BarCodeServiceViewModel:IBarCodeServiceViewModel
{
    public List<string> STMLocationItems { get; set; }


     private EnumLocalizer<ParserLocation> _selectedLocation = new EnumLocalizer<ParserLocation>() { Value = ParserLocation.Unknown };
            public EnumLocalizer<ParserLocation> SelectedLocation
            {
                get
                {
                    return _selectedLocation;
                }
                set
                {
                    Set(ref _selectedLocation, value);
                }
            }

    public BarCodeServiceViewModel()
    {
      STMLocationItems = new List<string>
                {
                    "Eject",
                };
                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    STMLocationItems.Add(i.ToString());
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: uh... becasue you bound the `Content` of that `ContentControl` to the `EnumLocalizer<ParserLocation>.Value`. The `Content` of `ContentControl` will be the DataContext of the controls of `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Oh I see thank you. I was thinking the same.